# Movie in which people go to a forest and build their new home but are killed by tree spirits

Tags: identify-this-movie

- People met something terrible, something like tree spirit.
- The tree spirits can take human's blood and body, only left bones and skin.
- The tree spirits are some kind of transparency, like crystal.
- They can not be hurt by sword or any physical method.
- They can not appear under the sunshine (not vampire), but they can manipulate the trees to gather their branches to create shadows.

People went to the deep forest (*on their way, the tree spirits controlled the trees to create darkness and kill many of them*) and found one broken steel, which says those tree spirits are afraid of water and can be killed by fire.

Finally people drew those tree spirits to the riverside and burnt them on a raft. But all people die too. The last man is the male lead of that movie, he told his wife to keep standing in the water but she was trying to help and then got killed, she till had a baby. The male lead went on to the raft and drew those tree spirits to it, and he set fire to the raft, burnt himself and all the overruns.

There are some other people who are like Indians. They didn't help much.
Just after all of those people were dead, the Indians went to the riverside and felt thankful for what those have done.

I used to think that is a Scotland/England movie, but not sure. The title of the movie is a tough one! Which movie is this?

**Edit:**
I used Google translate, and it told about "overruns", maybe it's wrong. Literally i think maybe it can be called "tree spirit". Hope you can understand this translation.

Comment: What is an *"overrun"*? When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? The title of this question doesn't seem to match the summary in the question body at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it's [Wraiths of Roanoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wraiths_of_Roanoke) (not awesome indeed, *Lost Colony* sounds much better to me). Movie is about English colonists in America who deal with ghost viking warriors. Details match up, except "tree spirits" part.

Comment: Yes, i have verified that it's just the movie. Thank you so much.